# Place string in front of underlined text in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2013

I have a bunch of questions with right (underlined) and wrong answers in a list like this:

```
1. What is love?
    -   baby
    -   don't
    -   hurt
    -   me
```

where only the part with the right answer `hurt` is underlined.

How can I replace the `-` with a `+` for the right answers?

Comment: Is the hyphen also underlined for the correct answer?

Comment: No, it's not. And also it's part of a list. I wanted to underline it or at least made it bold, but it didn't let me do it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start search, among the options; select to find `underline` *(preparatory step to create the macro)*
2. Start recording a macro, select a Short-cut key for the macro
3. Click to search for next occurence, exit the search dialog.
4. Use the CTRL+SHIFT and cursor keys to remove underlining (did you want this?)
5. Move the cursor to the `-`, delete and replace it with a `+`
6. Repeat the search, to find next occurence  *(prepare for repeating the macro)*
7. End recording

Now, replacing all the occurences is either hitting the shortcut key repeatedly until there is no more underlined text or alternatively, edit the macro to do the repeat (Press ALT+F11 to see the VBA editor, where you will find the code under `[+]Module`.

*Might be possible to search **`-.*` with `underline` code** appended, replace with **`+` appended with tab and underline codes** - with unix wild cards; never tried that though*